# Selenium: Wait for buttons that are visible but unclickable

Tags: java, selenium, wait

The page has a table. For filtering the table a pop up box is displayed. There's a button underneath the popup box. Right after i apply the filter, i need to click that button. What type of wait should i used.

Edit: I'm not sure if that button can be called unclickable.

Edit 2:

```
public void performTasks(){
        doCustomization();
        WaitUtils.waitUntilElementToBeClickable(driver,components.excelButton,5);
        components.clickExcel();
    }

public static void waitUntilElementToBeClickable(WebDriver driver, WebElement element, int timeout){
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,timeout);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
    }
```

Comment: You can use wait `elementToBeClickable` until button not get clickable. `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));`

Comment: I tried using that but it didn't work. I got something like "Other element would receive the click:"

Comment: Please write your track trace and your sample code for the better understanding with page HTML.

Comment: @BhavinD I have edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(element);